# How do I change x,y,z coordinates if I want to make a perspective projection?

Tags: projection

How do I supposed to modify x,y,z coordinates to make the perspective projection? I'm talking not about matrix, could you explain me each coodinate specifically? Like, x =... y=... z=...
I'm asking because the structure of my project does not contain matrix and vectors.

Comment: Generally you just divide X and Y by Z. You might want some adjustments, like using `Z*A+B` instead of just `Z`. But nothing stops you from actually looking up the perspective matrix, multiplying it by `x,y,z` on paper, then doing perspective division (all without substituting any numbers, using letters only), and then plugging the results into your code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - your comment could be an answer. It has enough information to answer the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "the structure of my project does not contain matrix and vectors"? Can't you write them yourself? Matrix math makes everything simpler. Also if you just divine `x` and `y` by `z` you get what is called "Weak Perspective Projection"